# Android Studio Giving Error While Building APK

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I was building an APK from Android Studio And first it gave error something like this:

Failed to find Build Tools revision 23.0.3
then i installed the above required tool and when i clicked on Build APK again, it gave me an error. Its image link is given, please help me how to solve it.
[Here is the link for image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sAVoz.jpg)

Comment: In your gradle file, are you using the version 23.0.3 or 23.2.1? Did you tried to change to 23.0.2?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! In the future. instead of including images of text, please copy and paste the error into your question. This ensures answerers will have an easier/quicker time answering your question and future users with the same issue will be able to find your question through searching.

Answer (score 0):

You should have this lines at your `build.gradle` file

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '23.0.3' // you will change this line with correct version
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId 'com.kapgel.consumer'
     }
```